# CronJob not starting in GoDaddy Shared hosting

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5

I am building an application in Laravel 5.2 and I am in need to build few CronJobs so I have written a command in my GoDaddy's cPanel like

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/bharat2016/public_html/artisan schedule:run
```

Basically I want to write php artisan schedule:run and it's working perfectly fine on my local but it's not running in my GoDaddy Hosting. Is the php path is perfect? P

Please let me know if there needs any other command then this

NOTE:
I have tried `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/bharat2016/public_html/artisan schedule:run`
and `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/bharat2016/public_html/artisan schedule:run  >/dev/null 2>&1`
but it's not working.

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try Godaddy online support?

Comment: yes. they built one demo cronjob with the command 'touch'. But it's not helpful to me as I have to run php artisan command. I asked them and they said they can't help more than creating demo cron job

Comment: And you are 100% sure you have the correct path to artisan?

Comment: yes it's under public_html folder only

Comment: Did you try executing in manually from the console?

Comment: Did you double check the rest of the path though. Normally it's something along the lines of `/home/user/domain/public_html/`

Comment: I tried the same code and command in my localhost and it's working perfectly fine

Comment: Did it work from the CLI _on the server_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/php-cli /home/bharat2016/public_html/artisan schedule:run >/dev/null 2>&1
```

`php-cli` needs to be written for accessing php command. I found it after lots of efforts so I want to give it an answer to be useful to other users who might face this issue in future

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
wget http://your_domain.com/page_name.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```